# Print out position of duplicate numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, search, duplicates

So I am writing a binary search method to finds the position in the array of the number given to it to. Return that position. So each time I compare a number in the array with what I am searching, print out the position in the array and the number at that position. Her is my code so far:

```
public static int binSearch(int[] arr, int key) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = array.length - 1;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if (key < arr[mid]) { 
           hi = mid - 1;
        } else if (key > arr[mid]) {
           lo = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
           return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};

    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, i);
        System.out.println(array[i] + " at " + index);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 0 at 0
 1 at 1
 2 at 2
 2 at 5
 2 at 8
 3 at 9
 3 at 10
 4 at -12
 4 at 11
```

My expected output would be

```
 0 at 0
 1 at 1
 2 at 2
 2 at 3
 2 at 4
 3 at 5
 3 at 6
 4 at 7
 4 at 8
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `index` rather than the `element` to the binary search function.

Try this

```
for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    int index = binarySearch(array, array[i]);
    System.out.println(array[i] + " at " + index);
}
```

And there are also a few problems with your binary search function..

Here's a corrected one

```
static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int key) { //Changed name to match with calling function name
int lo = 0;
int hi = arr.length - 1; //not array.length
while (lo <= hi) {

    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    if (key < arr[mid]) { 
       hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (key > arr[mid]) 
       lo = mid + 1;
    // you had one } here
    else return mid;
 }
 return -1;
}
```

This produces output

```
0 at 0
1 at 1
2 at 3
2 at 3
2 at 3
3 at 5
3 at 5
4 at 7
```

What is the use of using `binary search` to produce the output as you mentioned?. To get the output as you have mentioned you can use `linear search`.

Comment: Is there anyway else I can use the binary search to print the output as my expected? Thanks

Comment: @Benj Why do you want such a thing. Even to be clear `linear search` will stop when it finds the first occurrence. You are just printing the element followed by the index. You need no search for that

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is sorted, as required by the Arrays.binarySearch methods, the index of the first item is easily found as:

```
int index= Arrays.binarySearch(array, value);
```

A negative result indicates `value` is not in `array`. Now, if it *is* found and you are interested in the other indexes, you could simply step through the array until the value no longer matches:

```
public static void printIndexes(int[] array, int value){
  int index= Arrays.binarySearch(array, value);
  if (index < 0){
    return; // value not in array
  }
  while (index < array.length && array[index]==value){
    System.out.println(value + " at " + index);
    index++;
  }
}
```